# Enrich JPA-entity with non managed pojo

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a situation where I have some tables in a schema maintained by the project i´m in. These tables have the corresponding mapped jpa entities.

However, I wish to enrich one of the entities with a couple of fields from another schema. I though that a custom sql select could be used for this but I can not quite figure out how to do it.

The enriched data is only for display purpose and should not be updated.

I played around with @Subselect, @NamedNativeQuery and @Loader but without success. Highly simplified code below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class MyTableEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "XXX_SEQ_GEN")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "XXX_SEQ_GEN", sequenceName = "XXX_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    private Integer id;

    ... some properties


    private MyPojo myPojo;

    public MyPojo getMyPojo() {
        return myPojo;
    }

    public void setMyPojo(MyPojo myPojo) {
        this.myPojo = myPojo;
    }
}

public class MyPojo {

    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Hibernate is the jpa implementation.

Comment: In JPA, any attribute of an entity is stored in the table(s) of the entity. The only exception to that is where you decide to store some attributes in a "secondary table". There is no "read random things in from some other datastore container"

Answer (score 0):

You could use @Formula to fetch the read-only fields from another schema one by one.

```
@Formula(value="(SELECT t.extra_data1 FROM other_schema.other_table t WHERE t.id = id)")
@Basic(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
public Integer getExtraDataColumn1() {
   return this.extraDataColumn1;
}
```